# Is there any way to access to an event of my component (private declaration) from a thread (another class)?

Tags: multithreading, components, private, lazarus, freepascal

I created a component, in which I use threads, something like this:

```
type
  TEvent = procedure(sender:TObject) of object;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  protected
    Fvar:String;
    FMyEvent:TEvent;
  public
    Constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);override;
  published
    property MyProperty:String read Fvar write Fvar;
    property Event:TEvent read FMyEvent write FMyEvent;
  end;

  TMyThread = class(TThread)
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

implementation

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  if assigned (FMyEvent) then
    FMyEvent(Self);
end;
```

As you can see, I'm accessing to `FMyEvent` which is a private variable, from another class, so this generates a compilation error (Undeclared Identifier),I know its illogic to access to private variable from another class but I REALLY need to use this! I need that event to happen when `TMyThread` is executed.
I tried this code:

```
  type
  TEvent = procedure(sender:TObject) of object;

  TMyComponent = class(TComponent)
  protected
  Fvar:String;
  FMyEvent:TEvent;
  public
  Constructor Create(AOwner:TComponent);override;
  published
  property MyProperty:String read Fvar write Fvar;
  property Event:TEvent read FMyEvent write FMyEvent;
  end;
  TMyThread = class(TThread)
  private 
  fev:TEvent;
  protected
  procedure Execute; override;
  public
  constructor   Create(afev:TEvent);
  end;

  implementation
  procedure TMyThread.Create(afev:TEvent);//when i call this one i send the real Event of the component.
  begin
  fev:=afev;
  if assigned (FMyEvent) then
   FMyEvent(Self);      // it works here
  end;

 procedure TMyThread.Execute;
 begin
 if assigned (FMyEvent) then
  FMyEvent(Self);      //IT doesn't work here
  end;
```

As you can see, when I create the thread I send the properties of the component as parameters, I called the event in two different places, so when I call it in the constructor it works well,but when I call it in the execute procedure nothing happens!! however the condition:  `if assigned (FMyEvent)` is true in both cases ( I tried some tests to check this one). I guess the problem is relevant to "Self" should I replace by another owner? Why does the event work only when I call it in the create procedure?

Comment: Search for [If you want to make your application more flexible you can create an event for the thread](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Multithreaded_Application_Tutorial#The_TThread_Class) And read this page from begin to end carefully. You will find here every info about multithreading.

Answer (score 2):

1. *FMyEvent* is not private, it's protected.
2. It's also published as *Event* so accessible.
3. You need an instance to access the published event.

The error *Undeclared Identifier* actually comes from point 3 and not from the visibility.

It rather should be something like

```
procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  if assigned (Instance.Event) then
    Instance.Event(Self);
end;
```

Or you could create the thread with an event as parameter.

```
TMyThread = class(TThread)
private
  FMyEvent: TEvent;
public
  constructor construct(ev: TEvent);
  procedure Execute; override;
end; 

constructor TMyThread.construct(ev: TEvent);
begin
  FMyEvent := ev;
end;

procedure TMyThread.Execute;
begin
  if assigned (FMyEvent) then
    FMyEvent(Self);
end;
```

Comment: Your second suggestion helped me to try something, see my edit.